# Exterior differentiation under pullback question

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, pullback

In Loring Tu's book, [An Introduction to manifolds](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441973993), he uses the following proposition to prove that the pullback of a smooth $k$ form is a smooth $k$ form:

> **Proposition**:
> Let $F:N\rightarrow M$ be a smooth map. If $\omega$ is a smooth k-form then $$\mathrm dF^{*}\omega=F^{*}\mathrm d\omega.$$

However, my question is: Isn't the exterior derivative, $\mathrm d$ is a map $\Omega^{k}(M)\rightarrow \Omega^{k+1}(M)$ (space of smooth $k$, $k+1$ forms), so isn't he assuming that $F^{*}\omega$ is smooth?

Comment: There's no need to assume. If $F$ and $\omega$ are smooth, then $F^*\omega$ is automatically smooth as well.

Comment: Isn't $F^{*}\omega$ the pullback of the $k-form$, $\omega$?

Comment: Yes. One can show that the pullback of a smooth form by a smooth function is smooth.

Comment: I know, but the author used the proposition above to prove that the pullback of a smooth form by a smooth function is smooth. That's my whole point.

Comment: Are you sure about that last statement? This wouldn't be sufficient to prove smoothness, regardless.

Comment: Maybe what you've thinking of is that you can use the fact that the pullback of any smooth form by $F$ is a smooth form and the fact that $dF^*\omega=F^*d\omega$ to construct an explicit formula for the pullback of the smooth $k$-form?

Comment: @RachidAtmai I mean, $dF^{*}\omega$ isn't defined if $F^{*}\omega$ isn't smooth, right?

Comment: @orientablesurface My meager knowledge tells me that the exterior derivative is defined for all $k$-forms; it appears that to define $dF^*\omega$, one only need to know it $F^*\omega$ is a $k$-form and it does not necessarily have to be smooth for the exterior derivative to be well-defined. However as pointed above is $F$ and $\omega$ are smooth then $F^*\omega$ will be smooth.

Comment: @RachidAtmai: I do not know how to define $d\phi$ unless $\phi$ is at least a $C^1$ differential form. We're not going to talk about currents and distributional derivatives here. Smoothness of $F^*\omega$ is a separate question from computing exterior derivatives, as I already said. When we take exterior derivative, only certain combinations of partial derivatives appear, and that does not establish smoothness.

Comment: I do not own the book, so I can't verify whether OP is misinterpreting. But I surmise he is. The proof that the pullback of a smooth form by a smooth function is an entirely self-contained, separate argument. Start by showing $f^*dx^i$ is smooth.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you; so if I understood, OP's worry does not have any basis, he need not be worried. We simply  must assume the form to be $C^1$ to define $d$ on it, and at any rate this is not something that would follow from computing exterior derivatives?

Comment: @TedShifrin I found the book (just by google search), and the introduction to the corresponding section says (direct quote): The pullback of differential forms commutes with the exterior derivative. This fact, together with Proposition 18.11 that the pullback preserves the wedge product, is a cornerstone of calculations involving the pullback. Using these two properties, we will finally be in a position to prove that the pullback of a $C^\infty$ form under a $C^\infty$ map is $C^\infty$.

Comment: @ArcticChar:  Having taught this material dozens of times, I'll suggest he's using just $f^*dx^i = df^i$ and then using the wedge and pullback of functions. The OP still misled us, but it's more understandable. Thanks.

Comment: @Tedshifrin You are absolutely correct. In the book they used only $f^* dx^i = df^i$, but they claim to use $F^* \mathrm d\omega = \mathrm d F^*\omega$ (I think that might be a typo, or that's very misleading to say the least). I am writing up an answer to summarize this point.

Comment: I guess my point would be that this simple case is just the definition of pullback. So Tu is being very misleading when he says he uses this theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the corresponding section I agree that the author is wrong in claiming that $\mathrm d F^*\omega = F^* \mathrm d\omega$ is used to show that $F^* \omega$ is smooth. This is not necessary.

First recall (I am using the second edition):

> **Proposition 19.7**: If $F : N \to M$ is a $C^\infty$ map of manifolds and $\omega$ is a $C^\infty$ $k$-form on $M$, then $F^*\omega$ is a $C^\infty$ $k$-form on $N$.

**Proof (Sketch) given in the book**: In a local coordinates,
$$\omega = \sum_I a_I \mathrm dy^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm dy^{i_k}.$$
for some local smooth functions $a_I$. Then

\begin{align}
F^*\omega &= \sum (F^* a_I) F^* \mathrm dy^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge F^* \mathrm dy^{i_k} \\
&=  \sum (F^* a_I) \mathrm d(F^* y^{i_1}) \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm d (F^* y^{i_k}) \ \ \ \ \ (\text{Proposition }19.5)\\
&= \cdots \\
&= \sum (a_I \circ F)\frac{\partial (F^{i_1}, \cdots, F^{i_k})}{\partial (x^{j_1} \cdots x^{j_k})} \mathrm dx^J. 
\end{align}

Since

$$(a_I \circ F)\frac{\partial (F^{i_1}, \cdots, F^{i_k})}{\partial (x^{j_1} \cdots x^{j_k})}$$
are smooth, the author concludes that $F^*\omega$ is smooth.

Proposition 19.5 says that for any smooth $k$-form $\omega$ we have $F^* \mathrm d \omega = \mathrm d F^* \omega$.

As already pointed out by TedShifrin [in the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3786398/exterior-differentiation-under-pullback-question#comment7798913_3786398), only $F^* dy^{i_l} = d (F^* y^{i_l})$ is needed to show Proposition 19.7, and the proof in the book is exactly using just that. This fact is proved in the previous section (Proposition 17.10).

So I think it might be a typo to use Proposition 19.5 to prove Proposition 19.7. Indeed he needs only to use 17.10. Also it is confusing to put Proposition 19.5 before Proposition 19.7, that is, showing $F^* \mathrm d\omega = \mathrm d F^*\omega$ without first showing $F^*\omega$ is smooth. I did not check the whole book, but I guess the concept of $C^1$-differential form is not introduced. So it does not really make sense to talk about $\mathrm d F^*\omega$ without first showing that $F^*\omega$ is $C^\infty$, at least in the context of this book.

Comment: This clears everything up. Thank you.

Comment: Arctic Char, nice job getting Loring Tu's 'ringing endorsement'

Answer (score 7):

The way it stands, the placement of Proposition 19.5 is a mistake, because $F^*\omega$ needs to be $C^{\infty}$ before one can take its exterior derivative.  To fix this, in Proposition 19.7, replace the justification "(Proposition 19.5)" by "(Proposition 17.10)," and then move Proposition 19.7 to before Proposition 19.5.

I see that Arctic Char has proposed the same solution a while ago.  I give it my ringing endorsement.

Comment: Hi @Loring! :) :)